# How to reduce the time of STOP-THE-WORLD in Java GC

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

We know that in Java a full GC can hang the JVM, which can also be called STOP-THE-WORLD. In many applications, hanging the JVM too long will cause a lot of problems. I want to know how to reduce the time of STOP-THE-WORLD in GC? What are the potential drawbacks caused by reducing the time of STOP-THE-WORLD? (not considering the JVM without stop-the-world behavior)

Comment: Did you try other garbage collectors? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-140837.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches

- Create less garbage. A memory profiler will help.
- Use less heap.  A profiler can help reduce memory used.
- Use off heap memory instead.  There are number of libraries to store data off heap. e.g. Chronicle.
- Use more memory and GCs will happen less often, possibly be less serious when they do.  If you are using less than 32 GB of heap, this might be a quick win.
- Use a fully concurrent collector like Azul's Zing. It doesn't have a STW collector.

I would start with the memory profiler to reduce garbage and heap usage, and tune the GC.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects live long time you can try to use DirectBuffers from New I/O package. Their creation and reclamation is more expensive than the creation and reclamation of heap-based non-direct buffers because direct buffers are managed using OS-specific native code. This added management cost makes direct buffers a poor choice for single-use or infrequently used cases.

Direct buffers are also outside the scope of Java’s garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for your late answer! What is the new DirectBuffers related to  STOP-THE-WORLD. problems?